# BBCode to HTML database converter

Tags: html, sql, database, bbcode

Hi guys I have a little problem with my topics when I converted from vBulletin forum which stores topics as bbcode in the database to another forum board that use HTML instead, and I have about 4500 topic.

My request is a script or even an SQL query or any thing to convert all the topic table from BBCodes to HTML.

**note**: I tried an SQL replace query to replace each BBCode to its equivalent like: `[center]` to `<p>` and so on, it worked  but the the post wasn't well arranged but the link and image code seems to be good   .

So please any help to convert all the topics in the same time ?

Comment: How are you importing the data into the new database?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's that simple.

I believe your best bet would be to create some sort of script (in, say, PHP), to actually select all of your post records, parse them (PHP has the **[BBCode library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php)**),  then update each post one by one.

Prepared statements can help a lot with the performance hit, and since you (hopefully) only need to do it once, it can take more than an occasional PHP script.

Comment: tnx for your answer @Madara Uchiha I've tried something like bbcode parser but without success and couldn't integrate the function into the show post file so I asked for something to convert all the posts automatically

Comment: @anderson: I'm talking about a one-time-run-and-forget script that you run once, and it does the replacement in the database for you.

Comment: tnx @Madara Uchiha this is what I'm asking for. but I'm new at programing so can you give me a hand (^_^)